# Help with Arithmetic Progressions of Perfect Squares

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, integers, square-numbers, parametrization

Recently, I needed to generate all arithmetic progressions of three distinct perfect squares without any repeats. Mapping $\left(x, y\right)$ to such an arithmetic progression centered at $\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2$ with difference $4xy\left(y^2-x^2\right)$ for all $\left(x,y\right)\in\mathbb{X}$, where $\mathbb{X}:=\left\{\left(x,y\right)\in\mathbb{N}^2:0<x<y\right\}$, should solve this problem, as Fibonacci famously derived in his solution to the Congruum Problem. This means that for such an arithmetic progression $\left(b^2-h, b^2, b^2+h\right)$, there should a unique solution in $\mathbb{X}$ to the system of equations $x^2+y^2=b,4xy\left(y^2-x^2\right)=h$. However, in the case of the progression $\left(205^2,425^2,565^2\right)$, for which $h=138600$, these equations have no solution in $\mathbb{X}$, as can be seen in [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pifwza6oey) Desmos plot. What mistake am I making?

Comment: if $0< u<v<w$ and $u^2 + w^2 = 2 v^2,$  and $\gcd(u,v,w) = 1,$ then all are odd and $  \left( \frac{w-u}{2},\frac{w+u}{2}, v   \right)$ is a Pythagorean triple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You state

- Mapping $\left(x, y\right)$ to such an arithmetic progression centered at $\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2$ with difference $4xy\left(y^2-x^2\right)$ for all $\left(x,y\right)\in\mathbb{X}$, where $\mathbb{X}:=\left\{\left(x,y\right)\in\mathbb{N}^2:0<x<y\right\}$, should solve this problem,

and what you found out is that you were wrong. I will try to explain what your error was.

It took me a while to figure out that you were using the mapping
$$(x,y) \mapsto (2xy, y^2-x^2, x^2+y^2)$$

to generate Pythagorean triangles. What you have found out is that **the above mapping does not generate all Pythagorean triangles.**

This is the relationship between Pythagorean triples and arithmetic progressions of three perfect squares

$u^2+w^2=2v^2 \implies a^2+b^2 = c^2 \text{ where }
\left\{ \begin{array}{ccl}
   a &= &\frac 12(w-u)\\
   b &= &\frac 12(w+u) \\
   c &= &v
\end{array}\right.$

$a^2+b^2=c^2 \implies u^2+w^2 = 2v^2 \text{ where }
\left\{ \begin{array}{ccl}
   u &= & b-a\\
   v &= & c \\
   w &= & b+a
\end{array}\right.$

We find that

1. $\quad h=v^2-u^2 = c^2 - (b-a)^2 = (a^2+b^2) - (b^2-2ab+a^2) = 2ab$
2. $\quad h=w^2-v^2 = (b+a)^2 -c^2 = (b+a)^2-(b^2+a^2) = 2ab$

If we replace $a$ and $b$ with $2st$ and $t^2-s^2$ we get
$$h = 4xy(y^2-x^2) \tag{A}$$

which is just what you got; and then you found that you could not solve
$4xy(y^2-x^2)=138600$ for $x$ and $y$.

Let's go through the steps that led up to equation (A).

1. $\quad (u,v,w)=(205, 425, 565)$ yields $(a,b,c) = (180, 385, 425)$
2. $\quad 4xy(y^2-x^2) = 138600$

But you discovered that there is no solution to $4xy(y^2-x^2) = 138600$

We found the Pythagorean triangle that corresponds to the arithmetic progression $(205^2, 425^2, 565^2)$, so why can't we solve for $x$ and $y$?

The reason is that the mapping $(x,y) \mapsto (2xy, y^2-x^2, x^2+y^2)$ does not generate all Pythagorean right triangles!

A Pythagorean right triangle, $(a,b,c)$, is called **primitive** if $\gcd(a,b) =1$.

For example, $(5,12,13)$ is a primitive Pythagorean right triangle and $(9, 12, 15)$ is a Pythagorean right triangle, but it is not primitive since $\gcd(9,12) \ne 1$.

If you require that $\gcd(x,y)=1$ and $x \not \equiv y \pmod 2$ (one of $x$ and $y$ is even and the other is odd), then the mapping $(x,y) \mapsto (2xy, y^2-x^2, x^2+y^2)$ will generate all primitive Pythagorean right triangles.

If you put no restrictions on $x$ and $y$, you will generate other non primitive Pythagorean triangles but you won't generate all of them. For example, $(2xy, y^2-x^2, x^2+y^2) = (12, 9, 15)$ has no solution for $x$ and $y$.

So what you discovered is that $(180, 385, 425)$ is a non primitive Pythagorean triangle that cannot be expressed in the form $(2xy, y^2-x^2, x^2+y^2)$.

ASIDE:
The arithmetic progression of squares $(205^2, 425^2, 565^2)$ is not "primitive" either since $\gcd(205, 425, 565) = 5$. Dividing by $5$, we get the primitive triple $(u,v,w)=(41, 85, 113)$, which gives us the primitive Pythagorean triangle $(a,b,c) = (36, 77, 85)$. We then have to solve $4xy(y^2-x^2) = 85^2-41^2= 5544$. We must have $2xy = a = 36$. So $xy=18$. The possible values for $x$ and $y$ are now $(1, 18), (2, 9), (3, 6)$. We also need $y^2-x^2=b=77$. So $(x,y) = (2,9)$. No. This answer cannot be manipulated to solve the original problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I followed everything up until the step $v^2=c^2$. If $c=2v$, why is $v^2$ not equal to $\frac{1}{4}c^2$ instead?

Comment: Thank you again for your help. Your edit fixed my previous concern, but now I am confused by the step $\frac{1}{2}\left(u^2+v^2\right)=w^2$. Regardless of that specific issue, though, I am still somewhat confused as to what you are saying with regards to the parametrization given in my question. Are you saying that I misinterpreted it and just need to use Pythagorean Triples directly to generate arithmetic progressions of squares?

Comment: @EvanBailey If $u^2, v^2$, and $w^2$ are in AP, then $v^2-u^2 = w^2 - v^2 \implies u^2 + w^2 = 2v^2$ For every such triplet $(u,v,w)$ there exists a Pythagorean triplet, $(a,b,c)$ related to each other as shown above and there are all sorts of ways out there to generate Pythagorean triplets. I had to reedit my answer one more time. I have some troubles processing text mentally and this particular problem set all of my dials to 11.